# I need to call two APIs in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have 2 APIs, one call the products and the other one call the image of the products.
Products API: https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/Product

The second API is required call the ID of the products
Image API: https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/product/attachments?ProductID=

How can I call the second one to show the image.

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {  useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SingleContent } from "../../components/SingleContent/SingleContent";

export const All = () => {

    const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
  
    const fetchAllProducts = async () => {
        const  { data } = await axios.get('https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/Product',{
            headers: {
                "api-auth-accountid": process.env.REACT_APP_API_ID,
                "api-auth-applicationkey": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
              } 
        });

      
        console.log(data.Products);
        
        setContent(data.Products)
    
    }
   
    useEffect(() =>{
        fetchAllProducts();
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="pageTitle">All Products</h1>
            <div className="all">
                {content && content.map((c) => 
                    <SingleContent 
                        key={c.id} 
                        id={c.ID} 
                        name={c.Name} 
                        sku={c.SKU} 
                        category={c.Category}/> )}
                        
                       
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: ??what is your question. Do it the same way you've already done?
Also, consider putting your axios api in the dependency array

Comment: My question is, the image of each product is in the second API that needs to have the product ID as param. How can I call the second API?

Comment: be more specific what your problem is. Do you not know how to include the product ID or do you not know how to get it? Or do you not know how to wait for the first query to finish before you do the second?
What have you tried? 
StackOverFlow isn't meant to code for you, it's meant to help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside fetchAllProducts() you could map the data.Products array you get from the first request, call the second api for each item and add the product image to the item.

Then you can update the contents with the resulting array.

Edited: example code below.

```js
const fetchAllProducts = async () => {
        const  { data } = await axios.get('https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/Product',{
            headers: {
                "api-auth-accountid": process.env.REACT_APP_API_ID,
                "api-auth-applicationkey": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
              } 
        });

        const productsWithImage = data.Products
          .map(async product => {
            const imageUrl = await axios.get("https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/product/attachments?ProductID=" + product.id)
            return {...product, imageUrl }
          })
        
        setContent(productsWithImage)
    }
    
// Then you can use product.imageUrl when you map your products
```

Comment: Daniel, could you please write the code, Im new in React. Thanks.

Comment: @VNAleixo I added the code. I think it is alright but I haven't tested it. Hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: Hello @Daniel I posted the code above for your review. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` instead of `map` because it was returning a `Promise`. The problem is that if `setContent(result)` is called outside of the `for`, it only returns on register.

See the code:

```
export const AllHandle = () => {

    const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

    const fetchAllProducts = async () => {
        
        const { data }  = await axios.get("https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/Product?limit=10",{
            headers: {
                "api-auth-accountid": process.env.REACT_APP_API_ID,
                "api-auth-applicationkey": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
              } 
        });
        let result = [];
        const totaProducts = await data.Products;

        for (let product of totaProducts) {
           
            const imageUrl = await axios.get(`https://inventory.dearsystems.com/ExternalApi/v2/product/attachments?ProductID=${product.ID}`, {
                headers: {
                    "api-auth-accountid": process.env.REACT_APP_API_ID,
                    "api-auth-applicationkey": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
                  } 
              });
              
              const imgUrl = imageUrl.data
             
              result = [{ ...product, imgUrl}]
            }
           
            setContent(result)        
 }

 useEffect(() =>{
    fetchAllProducts();
}, [])   

 return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="pageTitle">All Products</h1>
        <div className="all">
            {content && content.map((c) => 
              
                <SingleContent 
                    key={c.ID} 
                    id={c.ID} 
                    name={c.Name} 
                    sku={c.SKU} 
                    category={c.Category}
                    attachment= { c.imgUrl[0].DownloadUrl}
                    />

                    )}
      
        </div>
    </div>
)

   
}
```

Comment: If the `fetchAllProducts` function is not shared in other hooks, I'd advise you to declare it inside the `useEffect` hook, otherwise it will be evaluated with every render. If otherwise the function needs to be shared, I believe you can use the `useCallback` hook, that prevents it from being evaluated when it's not needed.

Comment: Cool @GiorgioTempesta , I just updated it to be inside de useEffect, one thing is inside or outside the hook this APi is taking 5seconds to render 6 products.. Do you think I can improve the code to render fast?  Thanks.

Comment: The only optimisation that comes to mind is to wait for all promises to be resolved, instead of waiting for each one before you start the next one. This should be accomplished by creating an array of promises: in your case it would contain all the `imageUrl` variables (but without the await), and then just awaiting the resolution to `Promises.all()` to which you would pass the whole array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all?retiredLocale=it

Comment: The problem is that to show the images in the attachment endpoint I need to pass the product.ID param.

Comment: I think if you remove the `await` keyword and assign all the `imageUrl` variables to an array, you will have an array of Promises. Then if you call Promises.all() with the newly created array as a parameter you can await it. I think this is just an optimisation which might not impact heavily

Comment: Its working now. Thanks